# How to move from Mobile first to Desktop layout

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I wanna know how to move image 1 (mobile first) to image 2 (Desktop).
In mobile first, i created a div that contain all the details of image 1 and i want to change the order of all the items ? is Bootstrap the best solution ? I dont really know how to move from one to the other without creating other divs for desktop and hide the ones for mobile[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6b21h.png)

How to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the bootstrap there are order classes see [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/utilities/flex/#order)

Important you also have to include the bootstrap grid

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap-grid.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="d-flex flex-nowrap bd-highlight">
  <div class="order-1 order-sm-2 p-2 bd-highlight">First flex item</div>
  <div class="order-2 order-sm-1 p-2 bd-highlight">Second flex item</div>
</div>
```